# sm has no value, the default value seems to be false, but what does false mean?

Tags: material-ui

```
 <Grid item xs={12} sm container>
```

If you want to see the full example, please open [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/bnd0h).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of boolean values for the breakpoint props (xs, sm, md...) in material-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54624099/what-is-the-purpose-of-boolean-values-for-the-breakpoint-props-xs-sm-md-i)